# Null substitution for nullable enum mapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I need to write a mapper from a nullable enum to a regular one. Right now I use this

```
CreateMap<FromEnum, ToEnum>();
CreateMap<FromEnum?, ToEnum>()
    .ConvertUsing((source, dest, context) =>
    context.Mapper.Map<FromEnum, ToEnum>(source ?? FromEnum.SomeDefaultValue));
```

But I don't really like this solution. First, the intent is not very clear, and second, it only works if the source enum has the "default value" equivalent. Of course I can rewrite the second map using

```
CreateMap<FromEnum?, ToEnum>()
    .ConvertUsing((source, dest, context) =>
    source == null ? ToEnum.SomeDefaultValue : context.Mapper.Map<FromEnum, ToEnum>(source.Value));
```

but I think this will reduce the readability even further.

Is there some way to substitute the null for the entire map, and not just for a member? Can this be done by using just one map? (I never use a non-nullable `FromEnum`)

Comment: The default value for your enum should be zero and then you get this behavior without any extra map.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I just found out that automapper maps enums by value, and not by string names. But if you remove explicit map creation, it actually maps by name. But I need this behavior: map enums by name, provide a specific value for null, fail validation if the destination enum lacks some name that source have. Is it possible?

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Configuration-validation.html#custom-validations